# How to pause SFTP Connector in Mule ESB CE

Tags: sftp, polling, mule, connector

I need to pause a SFTP Connector from polling and then restart it after a specified interval, in Mule ESB CE 3.2.1.

Do you know if it's possible, by using Mule's API if necessary?

And, if it was possible, how could I disconnect and reconnect an SFTP client?

Thanks in advance,

Gabriele

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first try to practice pausing/stopping/starting through [JMX](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/JMX+Management), in order to determine exactly what Mule component you want to interact with (the SFTP connector? the flow that uses the connector? just the SFTP inbound endpoint?).

When you have decided exactly what it is you want to do, you can then either do it:

- Through JMX calls in the JVM directly on the Mule MBeans,
- Through Mule API calls starting by locating the target components in the [registry](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/registry/Registry.html).

Comment: Nice suggestion David, both JMX Agents and embedded Services work perfectly for our purposes.